# When we run debug in Azure data factory, does it run pipeline of entire data or it takes a sample data to run. & diff between validation and debug?

Tags: azure-data-factory

When we run debug in Azure data factory, does it run a pipeline for entire data or does it take a sample data to run?.I'm also curious to know what is the diff between validation and debug? I mean why two options If we have validated and passed then it should actually run the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

**Debug runs your pipeline only once using all the data** just to make sure all the components are defined correctly and pipeline should deliver the desired output. If debug runs the pipeline successfully, you can then create the Trigger to run  the pipeline at particular time or event. I suggest you to read this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#trigger-execution) to know more about Triggers Execution.

If there is any error in pipeline, read the error message and make the appropriate changes.

On the other side, **Validation just validates your pipeline and doesn't run it.** It makes sure that all the components (Linked Service, Datasets, Activities, IR, etc.), Activities Settings and other dynamic expressions(if applied) must defined correctly.

**Note:** The debug itself validates the pipeline before running it. So even if you didn't validate it, debug will take care of it. But, the best practice is always to Validate the pipeline first, Publish the changes and then Debug it. And if pipeline runs successfully, then create a trigger for automatic process.

Now, there is one more thing, i.e., **Debug mode in Mapping data flow.** Azure Data Factory mapping data flow's debug mode allows you to interactively watch the data shape transform while you build and debug your data flows. Learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-debug-mode?tabs=data-factory).

Comment: Hi @Gyan, if you find this answer useful and it actually helped you to clear the doubts, please accept it as an answer (click on check mark at left side of answer) to help other community members.